# Lodash return key of the _isEqual

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this code that will return if 2 of my objects that are being compared are equal:

```
let object = '{"menu_id":"3","menu_name":"eagle cake","qty":"1","special_instructions":"","modItems":[],"addOnItems":[]};

let cartData = '[{"menu_id":"3","menu_name":"eagle cake","qty":"1","special_instructions":"","modItems":[],"addOnItems":[]},{"menu_id":"8","menu_name":"Regular Yum Burger","qty":"1","special_instructions":"","modItems":[],"addOnItems":[]}]';

cartData.some(
   item => _.isEqual(
      _.omit(item, ['qty']),
      _.omit(object, ['qty']),
   )
);
```

Now, if this will return `true`, i want to get the object key so that I can manipulate it.

Example is when those 2 variables are compared, i want to return the key/index `0` since in `cartData` the key `0` has the `menu_id:3` , `menu_name:eagle cake`, etc..

I want to return the `key` or `index` of `cartData` because i will manipulate the data such as the `qty`, i will add that one on the `object`'s `qty`.

Thanks!

Comment: So you're looking for the index of object in cartData? I guess you could do it with _.findIndex(cartData, function(o) { return _.isEqual(o, object); });

Comment: yes, the index of the `cartData` that matches the `object` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `_.findIndex(cartData, function(o) { return _.isEqual(o, object); });`

findIndex is a function that takes an array and iterates over it and returns the first index that meets the condition in the function.
In this case it compares `object` to the elements of the array.

Comment: Hey, your works perfect, i just had to edit it to include the `_.omit()` :) I'll accept this as the correct answer! Thanks much!